# Finishing a HKLiveWorkoutBuilder workout with lots of HKWorkoutActivity instances is very slow

Tags: watchos, healthkit

I'm using the new watchOS 9 HKWorkoutActivity in my interval training app (Intervals Pro) for each interval. It's a great addition since all the intervals now show in the Apple Fitness app, however, if the workout has lots of activities then saving the workout is painfully slow. For example, on my Apple Watch Ultra I saved a workout with 63 activities and it took more than 1 minute. Here's a code snippet:

```
        try await builder.endCollection(at: workoutEndDate)
        try await builder.addMetadata(metadata)
        try await builder.finishWorkout() // This is SLOW
```

Is anyone else having the same issue?

Comment: While I haven't see the same issue you're seeing (yet), I was calling `try await builder.finishWorkout()` _before_  `try await builder.addMetadata(metadata)` in my app, which does not work. The docs say so (ha) but I still forgot. Thanks for sharing this question and inadvertently helping me out :)